# How to make this recursive function run faster?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
int add2_recurse(int a, int b) { // recursive

// Rule: Can't use the *, /, +, =, *=, /=, +=, -= operators.

// Can use: ++ and/or --

// No loops allowed; no static local or global variables.



// What I have so far

while(b--) {
    a++;
return a; }
```

---

```
int main() {
show_test(4, "add2", recursive);
cout << add2_recurse(4,5); cout<<" ";  // correct:   9
cout<<add2_recurse(-5, 15); cout<<" ";  // correct:  10
cout<<add2_recurse(20, -9); cout<<" ";  // correct:  11
cout<<add2_recurse(-7, -5); cout<<" ";  // correct: -12
cout<<endl;
```

---

When I run it, the correct outputs of "9 10 11 -12" are displayed, only the 11 and -12 display much more slowly. Any ideas on how I can get it to run faster?

Comment: I can't spot any  recursion in your example.

Comment: "this recursive function"? There are no recursive function for now.

Comment: So, how did you do on the interview, where you were asked this question?

Comment: It is weird that some of them take long time, Is this code really a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) after `}` is added after the posted function definitions?

Comment: It's hardly recursive and since `-` is not mentioned I guess one can simply do `return a-(-b);`

Comment: The 'while (b--)' is going to run for a really long time if b is negative. I'll leave it as an exercise to the poster to figure out why.

Comment: @Sylwester Pssh, my way is more fun.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your solution is wrong for two reasons. You don't use recursion, and you are using a loop.

As to why it runs so slow in the last two cases: whenever `b` is negative, `b` is decremented all the way down to the minimum possible integer number, then it wraps around to the maximum possible integer number, and finally it is decremented until it is 0. Assuming a 32 bit integer, you will have about 4 billion iterations of the loop.

You need to distinguish negative and positive values of `b`, and then either decrement or increment `a` as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any recursion, addition is quite trivially implemented in terms of the bitwise operations:

```
#include <limits.h> /* CHAR_BIT for pedantic correctness */

int add(int a_, int b_)
{
    /*
    Signed types tend to have UB. Prevent this by using unsigned.
    This might only work with twos-complement systems, sorry - patches welcome.
    */
    const unsigned a = (unsigned)a_;
    const unsigned b = (unsigned)b_;
    unsigned s = 0, c = 0;
    int i;

    /* constant-sized loop, can be trivially unrolled if you know how many bits are in an int (e.g. 16 or 32) */
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; ++i)
    {
        s |= ((a ^ b ^ c) & (1 << i));
        c = ((a & b) | (a & c) | (b & c)) & (1 << i);
        c <<= 1;
    }

    return (signed)s;
}
```

Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it.